# Effects of MVC SPA being removed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-spa

I am currently working on a tool and writing it in MVC SPA (single page application) and just now found out it was removed from the final release. What does that means to my project. do i have to stop working and move to MVC Internet application. I have not found much info in http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Please let me know the effects and possible work around on this issue

Thanks

Comment: final release of what ? MVC4 ? when did that happen ?

Comment: @Shyju this is what it read "An official release of ASP.NET SPA won’t be ready in time to ship with the final ASP.NET MVC 4 release. You can find the source code for ASP.NET SPA and follow the development effort on the ASP.NET CodePlex site."

Comment: Ah !  I missed that. Sorry about that. I should pay more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the SPA source code from the ASP.NET CodePlex page and compile it, then include the binaries in your application.  The current version is not 'complete', but the code that you've been depending on should still be as supported as it was in the Mvc 4 Beta release if you do that.

Comment: OK i get it. but what about the future, is this some thing like they are ditching SPA. I donot want to develop  something on a technology that has less or no support.

Comment: It looks more like they needed to ship MVC 4, and in order to make the deadline they had to omit SPA from the release.  There isn't any reason to believe the project is abandoned.  Until you see a notice that the project has been abandoned and/or support for the product has been discontinued, you can assume its still coming.